# How to access Smartsheet from PHP API?

Tags: php, api, smartsheet-api

It is my first time trying to connect Sheet from Smartsheet using API with PHP.
I cannot seem to connect and give me this error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartsheet\test.php on line 22

The variable `$sheetObj` is empty.
And in `Authorization: Bearer`, what does `Bearer` means? Is it a token name or it is always Bearer?

My future plan is to write into the row of smartsheet using PHP. Can anyone give me advice what went wrong with my code?

```
$baseURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1";
$sheetsURL = $baseURL . "/sheets/";
$getSheetURL = $baseURL . "/sheet/xxxxxxxxxxx";
$rowsURL = $baseURL . "/sheet/xxxxxxxxxxx/rows";

$accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 

// Create Headers array for cURL
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);  

$curlSession = curl_init($getSheetURL);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$getSheetResponseData = curl_exec($curlSession);

$sheetObj = json_decode($getSheetResponseData);
echo "<h1>Sheet name: ". $sheetObj->name ."</h1>";
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but important info:  version 1.1 of the Smartsheet API has been deprecated -- you should be using version 2.0 of the API.  Which means that the URI for the "Get Sheet" operation would be:  https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/SHEET_ID.  Docs here: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet.  Also -- re the format of the authorization header -- it should be the word "Authorization" followed by  a colon and a space, followed by the word "Bearer" and a space, followed by the value of your token.  (Looks like you have this correct.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After I changed to version 2.0  & sheet to sheets, it is still same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [stmcallister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42101925/1608110) and [Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103836/1608110) provided good information on how to troubleshoot your issue and some likely causes.

There were actually two issues with the code you provided.

1. As Scott mentioned you must point to the 2.0 version of the API.

   ```php
   $baseURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0";
   ```
2. You have a typo in your `$getSheetURL`. As is documented [here](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-sheet) the url is `/sheets/{sheetId}`. So your code should have the following:

   ```or-tag-here
   $getSheetURL = $baseURL. "/sheets/xxxxxxxxxxx";
   ```

Here is your code in a working state. Make sure to replace `YOUR_TOKEN` and also take a look at the output from `var_dump` (which I added to your code) to see what message it gives you.

```php
<?php
$baseURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0";
$getSheetURL = $baseURL. "/sheets/4925037959505796";
$accessToken = "YOUR_TOKEN"; 

$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken);

$curlSession = curl_init($getSheetURL);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$getSheetResponseData = curl_exec($curlSession);

// Remove this line when done debugging
var_dump($getSheetResponseData);

$sheetObj = json_decode($getSheetResponseData);

echo "<h1>Sheet name: ". $sheetObj->name ."</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: Yes. I have changed to this and it is still giving me same problem. Is It beacuase of I am using smartsheet free account?
$getSheetURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/4925037959505796";

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a working example. The `var_dump` line should give you a little more information about what is happening. If you can access the sheet via the [Smartsheet App](https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home) then you can access it via the API.

Answer (score 1):

[Search here on SO for the (partial) error message "*Trying to get property of non-object*"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Trying%20to%20get%20property%20of%20non-object%22) and you'll see lots of related posts. Essentially, this error means that your code is treating something as an object that's not actually an object. This would happen, for instance, when you try to access the `name` property of `$sheetObj` if the API request had previously failed for some reason and the contents of `$sheetObj` is therefore not actually an object.

I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I'd suspect (based on the error message, combined with the fact that you say "`var_dump($getSheetResponseData)` is `Bool(false)`) that the "Get Sheet" request may not be returning a successful response.  To troubleshoot, I'd suggest that you try running the exact same "Get Sheet" request (i.e., with identical URI, including sheet Id) using a tool like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) or via the commandline with cURL, and see if you get a successful response. If you can get your request working via Postman or cURL, it should be straightforward to update your code to send the same request, resulting in a successful response. See this section of the Smartsheet API docs for info about API Troubleshooting techniques using Postman or cURL: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#api-troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.1 of the Smartsheet API is [no longer supported](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs-v1/). You'll want to use [version 2](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#third-party-app-development).

To do this just change `$baseURL` to this:

`$baseURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0";`

Also, each of the objects in the API will be represented by plural endpoints. So, to get a sheet you'll use:

`$getSheetURL = $baseURL. "/sheets/xxxxxxxxxxx";`

To get the rows you'll use:

`$rowsURL = $baseURL. "/sheets/xxxxxxxxxxx/rows";`

Bearer is the [type of Authorization header](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re) that you're passing to the API, and the type that is required by the Smartsheet API.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. But It is still the same error.  "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartsheet\test.php on line 22". The variable $sheetObj is empty.

Comment: If I remove the the `**` characters that are before and after the line $sheetObj = json_decode($getSheetResponseData);, your code works for me. I would recommend doing an echo $getSheetResponseData to see what response you're getting back from the API.

Comment: Thanks you. I add ** to highlight. I didn't run the code with **.  By the way, I am using smartsheet free account. Is it because of free account?  The echo is " "  and var_dump($getSheetResponseData)  is Bool(false).

Answer (score 0):

Hello to use the smartsheet API connection to PHP, the API version 2.0 is used, because the older version is obsolete, the code for the connection is as follows:

```
$baseURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets";
// Insertar access token generado en SmartSheet
$accessToken = "YOUR_TOKEN";
// Creación del Headers Array para el Curl
$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer $accessToken",
"Content-Type: application/json");

//Conexión de la API de SmartSheet
 $curlSession = curl_init($baseURL);
 curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 //Establece la sesión del Curl
 $smartsheetData = curl_exec($curlSession);


 // Asignar respuesta a un objeto PHP
 $createObj = json_decode($smartsheetData);
```